# Loading not-so-well-formed XML into XDocument (multiple DTD)

Tags: .net, dtd, doctype, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

I have got a problem handling data which is almost well-formed XHTML document except for it has multiple DTD declarations in the beginning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

I need load this data into XDocument object using only the *first* DTD and *ignoring* the rest declarations. It is not possible to completely ignore DTD processing because the document may have unusual characters like `&acirc;` or `&euro;` etc.

The text is retrieved from an external source and I have no idea why it comes like this.

Obviously my naive attempt to load this document fails with `System.Xml.XmlException : Cannot have multiple DTDs`:

```
        var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
                                    {
                                        DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
                                        XmlResolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver(),
                                        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document,
                                    };
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, xmlReaderSettings))
        {
            return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }
```

What would be the best way to handle this kind of data?

P.S: I forgot to mention, that the data comes from a `Stream` which may or may not make the string manipulation a little bit more complex

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an XmlReader setting that will ignore this problem, but you could always use standard string manipulation to remove the extra doctypes.